# Пример реализации OAuth на своём сайте?

Tags: php

Хочу реализовать OAuth на своем сайте, ну чтобы можно было авторизоваться через мой сайт, хочу найти пример реализации. В гугле ищу, но находит только реализация как сделать авторизации типа через Яндекс, вк и т.д. Можете пожалуйста показать статья, где на примере это показано

Comment: А как вы искали и главное что? [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749),  [Git](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server), [Habr](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/115163/)

Comment: так я все это видел. Я же написал, хочу посмотреть пример реализации этого. То, что вы скинули, я это уже давно видел, это обычная статья

Comment: Если вы всё это видели - то видели и пример реализации(git), или вы считали что это поднимается в одну строку без кучи кода?

Comment: На гите нет реализации, это библиотека. Мне библиотека не нужна

Comment: Ну тогда мы видим разный гит, я там вижу папку с примерами использования данной библиотеки(собсно сервера oAuth) :)

Comment: так мне не нужна библиотека

Comment: Вся эта библиотека и есть "пример своего сервера oAuth". вы вообще по первой ссылке заглянули? или вы считаете что документация на сотню страниц должна работать из коробки одной строкой кода?